# Multiple Search Fields on the Same Page with Suggested Results

Tags: coveo

We have implemented a `global Coveo search box`, in our global header on our site that drives to our search page. This appears on our search page as well. Both the search box on the search page and the global search box use this for suggested results:

[https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV4/Provide+Result+Suggestions](https://developers.coveo.com/x/CIIUAg)

However, on our search page, we now get a **JavaScript error** on the page.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(…)`

If I remove the `Coveo Omnibox Result List View` from the global search box on the page it works fine again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you just found a new bug in Coveo for Sitecore 4.0.450!

It is caused by a new fix that was introduced in the October version. It looks for an `input` in all `.CoveoSearchbox`es to bind an event when the `CoveoForSitecoreOmniboxResultList` component is added. However, the input is not *yet* loaded, because the Search page loads *after* the `CoveoForSitecoreOmniboxResultList` component.

I have managed to come up with a quick **workaround** that will fix your problem:

Add the following `input` tag like this in your **SearchView.cshtml** file:

```html
<div class="CoveoSearchbox CoveoSearchPageSearchbox" ... >
    <input style="display:none"></input> <!-- This line here -->
</div>
```

The bug will be fixed in the next version :)